# python - end of page in txt file

Tags: python, parsing, text

i have this little problem. Is there any way how to recognize where is the end of current page in text file ?

I have some PDF files which i convert to plain text. Now i want to split every page and work with this separated pages. Is there any solution to do it? I work with only converted documents - there are page numbers but that is not accurate when there are some other numbers in text.

PDFMiner which i use, have some variable for converting page, which i can use. But there is a lot of other programs for PDF converting and i want to write a program for general use.

have somebody please some advise ? Thank you

Comment: The concept of multiple pages in a text document doesn't exist. You're thinking of Word documents or PDFs that are formatted documents. A text file is not formatted, and there is no end of page. If you have 2000 lines in the document then line 2000 is the end of page.

Comment: pure text files have no formatting whatsoever, so it is not possible to paginate these files.  If however you are happy with the pagination of the original pdf you should convert each pdf page to separate text files.

Comment: @JosephJames ,ColinDickie:: you added the most useful about file handling concepts thanks just i too came to know this .

Comment: Thank you guys, you help me, too bad

Comment: How about looking for something consistent at the end of every page of the PDF document like the footer and using that as a marker to split them back into separate pages. 

Also you should still try using the page numbers even if there are other numbers on the page since you know what page number it would be. It may still not be perfect but since you know the page number and the fact it will be a stand alone string, it would hopefully help with some false positives.